# Diff tool to display complete tree, with SVN support

Tags: windows, gratis, diff, subversion

This is a software development specific question.

In case of merges in SVN, I often want to compare all files of the branch against all files of the trunk.

Today I am using [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/), which can compare folders like this:

[image: WinMerge Screenshots]

Winmerge can

- ignore source control files, i.e. the `.svn` folder
- open folders by clicking on it

However, it cannot

- ignore files that are ignored by SVN, i.e. have the - icon
- display all files as a tree so that folders needn't be opened

Is there a diff tool that can display a complete tree, ignoring the SVN-ignored files?

It has to be

- for Windows 7 SP1 x64 (and higher if possible)
- free / open source

Comment: Since you are using WinMerge, you might want to know about [WinMerge2011](https://bitbucket.org/jtuc/winmerge2011/downloads).  Despite it's misleading name, it currently has more maintenance and features than regular WinMerge.  I don't think it will do what you want for this specific task, but I thought you may find it helpful. :-)

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: thanks for this link. Installed :-)